# Can a non-preemptive recursive algorithm be tail recursive as well?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tail-recursion

By definition:

**Non-Premptive Recursion**: *if a function calls itself from one of its parameters then such a recursion is called Non-Premptive Recursion. Example: Ackermann's function is an example of Non-Preemptive Recursion*

```
private static int Foo(int i)
{
    if (i == 1000000)
        return i;

    if (i % 100 == 0)
    Console.WriteLine(i);

    return Foo(Foo(i+1));//last statement of the function
}
```

Here the recursive call to `Foo` is the last statement of the function and is not part of an expression which makes it a tail recursive call. But on the other hand since the `Foo` function has been called as an argument so it will result in creation of call stack frames which can't be discarded until the termination condition has been reached.

In tail recursion, compiler can optimize the tail recursion calls as it need not maintain the call stack frames. So my question is that - Is my recursive call to `Foo` in the above code snippet really a tail recursive call?

Comment: Are you sure that's an actual term? I can only find one source using it, in some random-ass blog. Also, you're trying to use a function return of `void` where an `int` is needed.

Comment: @user2357112 I encountered this term while reading a book on data structures. Here is a [link](http://geekexplains.blogspot.in/2008/10/recursion-advlim-factorial-ackemanns.html) referring to the same. Updated the code to fix signature issue.

Comment: Yeah, that's the random-ass blog I was talking about. What data structure book are you reading? That phrase has no hits on Google Books, and it doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Also, now you're falling off the end of a non-void function without returning anything.

Comment: @user2357112 here is the [link](http://www.amazon.in/Expert-Data-Structures-CD-Patel/dp/8190645153/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1474588833&sr=1-1) to the book I'm referring to currently.

Comment: The best way to answer this is to compile the code with optimizations enabled and look at the assembly code.

Comment: Never heard of it in 45 years. 'Calls itself from one of its parameters' is meaningless. Google has exactly three hits on this term, and this question is one of them.

Comment: It sounds like someone misunderstood "primitive recursion". That's the best guess I can make for where they got this term.

Answer (score 1):

> Can a non-preemptive recursive algorithm be tail recursive as well?

Yes.

> Is my recursive call to `Foo` in the above code snippet really a tail recursive call?

Which one? There are two recursive calls:

- `…(Foo(i+1))…` - not tail-recursive
- `return Foo(…);` - tail-recursive

The outer, tail-recursive one can be optimised:

```
private static int Foo(int i) {
    while (i != 1000000) {
        if (i % 100 == 0) Console.WriteLine(i);
        i = Foo(i+1);
    }
    return i;
}
```

The compiler *may* deduce that `Foo` always returns `1000000` (if it returns), and therefore further rewrite the method to another tail-recursion, but that requires advanced reasoning and is not a simple transformation:

```
private static int Foo(int i) {
    if (i != 1000000) {
        if (i % 100 == 0) Console.WriteLine(i);
    } else {
        return i;
    }
    return Foo(i+1);
}
```

which then can be transformed by the tail-recursion rule into

```
private static int Foo(int i) {
    while (i != 1000000) {
        if (i % 100 == 0) Console.WriteLine(i);
        i = i+1;
    }
    return i;
}
```